# GitLab CI denies access to push using a deploy key with write access

Tags: ssh, continuous-integration, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci-runner

I added a deploy key with write access to my GitLab repository. My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file contains:

```
- git clone git@gitlab.domain:user/repo.git
- git checkout master
- git add myfile.pdf
- git commit -m "Generated PDF file"
- git push origin master
```

The deploy key works when cloning the repository.
Pushing is not possible, even if the deploy key has write access.

```
remote: You are not allowed to upload code.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@domain/user/repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Comment: Not sure: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/deploy_tokens/#limiting-scopes-of-a-deploy-token

Comment: This is about deploy tokens, not about deploy keys. Can they be used for the described purpose?

Comment: Good point. I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just encountered the same problem and saw this question without answer, so there is my solution.

## Problem

The problem is caused by the fact that the remote url used by git to push the code is in the form `http(s)://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@git.mydomain.com/group/project.git`.
This url is using `http(s)` protocol so git doesn't use the `ssh` deploy key that you setup.

## Solution

The solution is to change the push url of the remote `origin` so it matches `ssh://git@git.mydomain.com/group/project.git`.
The easiest way to do so is to use the [predefined variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) `CI_REPOSITORY_URL`.

Here is an example of code doing so by using `sed`:

```sh
# Change url from http(s) to ssh
url_host=$(echo "${CI_REPOSITORY_URL}" | sed -e 's|https\?://gitlab-ci-token:.*@|ssh://git@|g')
echo "${url_host}"
# ssh://git@git.mydomain.com/group/project.git

# Set the origin push url to the new one
git remote set-url --push origin "${url_host}"
```

Also, those using docker executor may want to [verify the SSH host key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#verifying-the-ssh-host-keys) as suggested by the gitlab documentation on [deploy keys for docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#ssh-keys-when-using-the-docker-executor).

So I give a more complete example **for docker executor**.
The code is mainly from gitlab documentation on [ssh deploy keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#ssh-keys-when-using-the-docker-executor).
In this example, the private deploy key is stored inside a variable named `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY`.

```sh
create:push:pdf:
  before_script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - git config --global user.email "email@example.com"
    - git config --global user.name "User name"
    - gitlab_hostname=$(echo "${CI_REPOSITORY_URL}" | sed -e 's|https\?://gitlab-ci-token:.*@||g' | sed -e 's|/.*||g')
    - ssh-keyscan "${gitlab_hostname}" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    - git checkout master
    - git add myfile.pdf
    - git commit -m "Generated PDF file"
    - url_host=$(echo "${CI_REPOSITORY_URL}" | sed -e 's|https\?://gitlab-ci-token:.*@|ssh://git@|g')
    - git remote set-url --push origin "${url_host}"
    - git push origin master
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I needed some time to test this. It works! Thank you very much. It is perfect for generating pdf files with LaTeX.

Comment: My pleasure, I was glad to found that I wasn't the only one asking myself this question. The error is not quite obvious though.
For my part, I use it daily for software versioning and changelog edition since a month without problems.

Comment: Please note, in case you runner is on windows, the environment variable format is something like this: `%CI_REPOSITORY_URL%`. Used versions: Gitlab: 11.x and Gitlab CI Runner: 11.x