# Gitlab CI job should change source code. poetry-dynamic-versioning

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, python-poetry

I would like to run a job which launches `poetry-dynamic-versioning` and add new version to `pyproject.toml` and `__init__.py`.

Is it possible to change source code with CI job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is possible. You need the following steps

1. [Generate a ssh key pair](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html) for your CI processes.

   `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "Key for Gitlab CI" -f gitlab-ci_ed25519`

   !Do not add a passphrase to the SSH key!

   This gives you two files `gitlab-ci_ed25519.pub` and `gitlab-ci_ed25519`
2. [Create a deploy key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_keys/index.html) with write access for your repo (also possible on group level). Use the public key from step 1 for it: `gitlab-ci_ed25519.pub`.

   *The Deploy Key section can be found under `-/settings/repository`*
3. [Protected Branches](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html). For your use case it may be necessary to allow the deploy key to push to protected branches.

   *Protected branches can be found under `-/settings/repository`*
4. [Create a variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` with the private key from step 1: `gitlab-ci_ed25519`.

   *The variable section can be found under `-/settings/ci_cd`*

   **Note**: You can add some security to the `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` variable by setting it as "protected". If selected, the variable is only available in pipelines that run on protected branches or tags. More info on security can be found [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secrets/index.html).
5. [Follow this guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#ssh-keys-when-using-the-docker-executor) and create a `.gitlab-ci.yml` that uses the deploy key to access the repo.

- Now your tools (poetry-dynamic-versioning, git) should be able to modify files and push them back to your origin.
- A similar example (for docker executer) can be found here: [GitLab CI denies access to push using a deploy key with write access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55224376/gitlab-ci-denies-access-to-push-using-a-deploy-key-with-write-access) (I can confirm that it works)

6. [Job Control](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html) (Optional). Since a push from Gitlab-CI can trigger the pipeline again you may want to add some `rule` directive to control when to start the job and to prevent an endless loop.

Comment: I have still issue with:  Error loading key : invalid format. I have tried ed25519, rsa, protected - not protected. —–BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY—–
—–END RSA PRIVATE KEY—–.                                                                                         - echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -    or                                                   - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -  doesn't work

Comment: The private key is stored as string in the variable or did you upload a file? It should be stored as string.

Comment: As a string. I have tired also - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 -d | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -. The same result

Comment: hm. did you copy the string through an editor? Maybe an issue with line endings from windows. like reported from some here https://serverfault.com/questions/854208/ssh-suddenly-returning-invalid-format. Maybe a missing LF at the end.... hard to say. I used `cat` to print the key on console and copied it from there.

Comment: Hi, my reputation is too low to upvote. But I will do it in the nearest future.